# Does food and prayer become makruh after junub if not bath?

Tags: salat, sex, food, ghusl, makruh

I been told that after junub one should need to have bath/gusul before having food or to pray. Although one can have food or do whatever they want but it is considered makruh and is believed that blessing from home stop coming.

If that is true then every time a couple became intimate and in state of junub, it would mean to bath every time and while some might live with families or with relatives, it does get noted of why someone is showering couple of times.

My question is, that is it true that eating food or prayer become makruh if you do not have shower after junub?

Reference will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intercourse entails ritual impurity. One can not perform prayers(Salah) or visit a Mosque while in a state of ritual impurity, and everything else is permissible. Ritual impurity caused by intercourse is removed by performing Ghusl(bath) See [IslamQA](https://islamqa.info/en/20847).

Regarding eating, it is not necessary to perform Ghusl before that, though majority opinion is that it is considered *mukruh*(disliked) to sleep without performing Wuzu(ablution) and to eat without washing the hands ... though there are some conflicting Hadith on the matter.

> Whenever the Prophet (ﷺ) intended to sleep while he was Junub, he used
>   to wash his private parts and perform ablution like that for the
>   prayer [Saheeh Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/5/40)
>
> 'A'isha reported: Whenever the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) had sexual
>   intercourse and intended to eat or sleep, he performed the ablution of
>   prayer. [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/3/22)
>
> It was narrated from 'Aishah that if the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) wanted
>   to sleep while he was Junub, he would perform Wudu', and if he wanted
>   to eat he would wash his hands. [Sunan Nisai](https://sunnah.com/urn/1002580)

One can perform intercourse multiple times and bath only once after that. In common practice intercourse is performed at night after the last prayers of the day(Isha) and before the first prayers of the next day(Fajr), and a bath is taken before the Fajr prayers. The other common practice is to perform it in the afternoon between the Zuhr and Asr prayers, and to perform a bath before the Asr prayers. Normally its not a custom to eat at these times. Daily morning and occasional evening showers are usually taken even if intercourse is not performed, for general hygiene purposes, so it blends in ... otherwise Muslim families are usually understanding and respectful about the matter.

Answer (score 0):

No it is allowed to eat food after having sexual relations without doing ghusl. The reason that people say that it is makruh is because you are impure so it is best to do wudhoo before eating and do ghusl when desired. The reason is that 
Aa’ishah (may Allaah be pleased with her),  said that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him), when he wanted to eat or sleep at the time when he was junub (in a state of impurity following intercourse), he would do wudoo’. (Narrated by Muslim, al-Hayd, 461). Shaykh Ibn ‘Uthaymeen said in al-Sharh al-Mumti’
The one who is junub should do wudhoo before sleeping but it is mustahabb and not obligatory. This is the same case with eating. Some scholars say that 'It is not makrooh for someone to eat or drink without wudhoo.

Comment: I have updated question, with a little new detail.

Answer (score -2):

Short answer : No .
Detailed answer : after semen gets out of the body prays and "roozeh" are not acceptable . Actually it is harram . 
But about eating food . If you are *sunni* you are not allowed to eat . But if you are *shia* you should take bath ( ghusl ) as soon as you can . And there is no law in sharia for the shia people that can't eat food .
But quran allows Muslims that if they do something that is haram unintentional ( means he / she don't know doing this is haram or forget that he shouldn't do that ) **Not committed any sins or haram** .
Hope that Be helpful ...